# NSUnknownKeyException, need help troubleshooting

Tags: objective-c

For the life of me, i am not sure what i changed here, but all of a sudden i get

> 2011-11-03 00:00:22.408 UnblockMe[26904:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception > 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this > class is not key value coding-compliant for the key puzzleNumber.'

`Puzzle1` class does not reference `puzzleNumber` anywhere in the code. There is no such thing in the program, named `puzzleNumber`.

Where might this error come from and what can i do to resolve it?

Comment: Have you inspected your nib files as well?

Comment: Yes. No connections referencing this value is seen anywhere

Comment: Sounds like a job for clean and rebuild. I’d still grep for `puzzleNumber` in the project, though.

Comment: I "clean"(ed), but this did not resolve the issue. In this example, does error indicate that "puzzleNumber" is a variable referenced somewhere

Comment: It’s being used as a key somewhere that uses `-setValue:forKey:`. One of such places is nib loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is the weirdest thing i've seen so far. I am posting this, as others may find to be in the similar situation.

First of all, the error is absolutely inaccurate. The issue has nothing to do with the `puzzleNumber`.

Before last (failed) run, i refactored my main `NIB` via `Xcode 4.2` refactor Utility. Once complete, **refactor DID NOT update the AppDelegate.m** file to reflect the change.

Xcode was trying to load the XIB which no longer existed and all sorts of weird things happened (evidently).

If i am incorrect, certainly correct me, but editing AppDelegate fixed the issue completely.

Comment: I found the same thing .. the error was due to something unrelated to the set method for the property. In my case I set a view to use a custom class that did not exist. To fix I just dragged a new View Controller onto the story board, copied the UI element from the original to the new and ctrl-drag to reestablish the outlets and actions.  Thanks for the idea to look beyond the obvious.